# The webpage is getting scrolled to the top location while destroying isotope and resetting it

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-isotope

I'm using http://isotope.metafizzy.co/'s `isotope` plugin to create grid layout. On clicking any of the grids, I display a modal popup showing the details. On closing the modal popup, control comes back to the old isotope grid layout. The content of the modal popup are `hidden` under the part of the isotope item. I had problems with the content in the modal popup being displayed properly. So, what I did is, on clicking any of the isotope's grid `<a>` item, I used `$.isotope('destroy');`. Only then, the modal popup worked properly. Further, upon closing the modal popup, I re-initialise the isotope grid using the following code:

```
    $("#container").isotope({
     itemSelector:".item",
     masonry:{
     columnWidth:100,
     gutterWidth:20
     },
     animationOptions:{
     duration: 750,
     easing: 'linear',
     queue: false
    }
    });
```

I have added `return false;` at the end of all the functions handling `<a>` element's `onclick` event (using `jQuery`'s `delegate()` function).

Upon re-initialisation, the page scrolls back to the top. Other than this, there is no problem with the usability of the page. I'm stuck. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need to use the destroy method or any special tricks with modal windows and Isotope; have you tried [this here](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2) or similar ones to show static or dynamic content? It does work [here](http://www.16percent.net/) to reveal more stuff. If you only worry about the page scroll, Lix gets the green : )

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the `isotope` plugin you are using, but preventing that page scroll as a result of clicking on `<a>` elements **can** be prevented.

Instead of `return false`, you could try `preventDefault()`.

On a click handler (for example) you would do this -

```
$('a').on('click',function(e){
  // other code here
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I guess the problem is not with the `<a>` tag. It is a problem with the page getting reset upon initialisation of $.isotope(). Any suggestions?